# WordPressのソース を Githubで管理する場合、どこまで管理対象にするか

Tags: git, wordpress, github

wordpress のソース を github で管理する場合、どのディレクトリまでソース管理する必要がありますでしょうか？
今考えているのは下記２つです。
・テーマディレクトリ(`/wp-content/themes/`)以下のみを管理する場合
・アップロードディレクトリ以外(`/wp-content/upload`)全てをgitで管理する場合

上記２つでどのようなメリット・デメリットがあるか教えていただけますでしょうか？
また、それ以外のよりよい管理方法がありましたら教えていただけたらと思います。
テーマディレクトリ以下を管理する理由としては、1つのwordpressにpc/spでテーマ切り替えを行っているためです。
1つのwordpressに対して1テーマのみで運用している場合は`/wp-content/themes/original_theme` のみを管理すると読み換えていただければと思います。
プライベートリポジトリを利用し、ソースの変更は全てテーマディレクトリで行っており、プラグインを利用しております。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

運用を決めたので自己解決として記入します。
僕は以下の管理方法にしました。
・アップロードディレクトリ以外(`/wp-content/upload`)全てをgitで管理する

理由としては、下記の場合に対応できるためです。
・プラグインなどを更新した際にサイトが停止してしまった場合
・プラグインを誤って消してしまった場合
・wp-includeなどのコアファイルを書き換える必要があった場合

余談ですが、ローカル環境を構築するときも`git clone` でソースを全て引っ張ってきて、
画像を入れてDB流しこむという流れで楽だなと感じました。